# Adding one day to Julian date

Tags: unix-timestamp, julian-date

I am trying to find an easy way to add a day to a  julian date which is not the current date. I prefer to do this in unix. But can also do this in hive.

appreciate your help!

Comment: Define your terms. What do *you* mean by "julian date"? What do you mean by "do this in unix"? Voting to close as unclear. Always search Stack Overflow before posting. Date-time and timestamp issues have been addressed many many times before. If you need guidance, seek a discussion/forum site such as http://www.CodeRanch.com/. This site is dedicated to narrowly-focused questions on a specific problem with a likely spot-on solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pandas implementation that is quite automated:

```
import pandas as pd

date = ....

julian_date = pd.Timestamp(date).to_julian_date()
```

Check out the pandas documentation for more references: [pandas timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_julian_date.html)[pandas to julian](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_julian_date.html)

You may need to convert your date to a format that pandas can parse.